# Loop over nodes with if condition and create new node

Tags: xslt

I would like to create a new node based on if condition, but I got stuck:

Input:

```
<SHOP>
    <ITEM>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <TP>
            <name>Color</name>
            <size>red</size>
        </TP>
        <TP>
            <name>Code</name>
            <size>14</size>
        </TP>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <name>Bananas</name>
        <TP>
            <name>Color</name>
            <size>yellow</size>
        </TP>
        <TP>
            <name>Code</name>
            <size>16</size>
        </TP>
    </ITEM>
</SHOP>
```

I am trying to use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="SHOP/ITEM/TP">
    <PARAM>
        <xsl:if test="name = 'Color'">
            <span class="color"><xsl:value-of select="./size"/></span>  
        </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="name = 'Code'">
            <span class="code"><xsl:value-of select="./size"/></span>  
        </xsl:if>
     </PARAM> 

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only problem is, that the output is a multiple `<PARAM>` node, while I want one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOP>
   <ITEM>
      <name>Apple</name>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="color">red</span>
      </PARAM>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="code">14</span>
      </PARAM>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <name>Bananas</name>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="color">yellow</span>
      </PARAM>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="code">16</span>
      </PARAM>
   </ITEM>
</SHOP>
```

Desidered output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOP>
   <ITEM>
      <name>Apple</name>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="color">red</span>
         <span class="code">14</span>
      </PARAM>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <name>Bananas</name>
      <PARAM>
         <span class="color">yellow</span>
         <span class="code">16</span>
      </PARAM>
   </ITEM>
</SHOP>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="ITEM">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except TP" />
        <PARAM>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TP" />
        </PARAM> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TP">
    <span class="{lower-case(name)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="size"/>
    </span>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent, just: for easier read I simplified input XML and I have more nodes in `<ITEM>` (like `<name>Apple</name>`): now we just copying one element into result `<xsl:apply-templates select="name" />`. What if I have multiple nodes here (which are not <TP>)?